# Using ADAL Javascript to authenticate to Azure AD non-interactively

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, adal.js

We would like to create a HTML5/CSS3/Javascript client-based application to authenticate to Azure AD in a non-interactive manner, henceforth obtaining the token to be used to create Web API requests.

Is this possible using ADAL JS? 
If yes, would appreciate some code samples on how it can be done.

Thank you.

Comment: By non-interactive manner, do you mean not prompting user for credentials?

Comment: @ezile Yes sir. Indeed.

Comment: Any luck finding a solution? Would you be able to post your solution?

Answer (score 0):

Adal.js in its present state does not support non-interactive authentication flows.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is not possible today, but I believe the team is working on enabling it in the future